# How to create a background webworker in javascript (html5, JS)?

Tags: javascript

How can I create a web worker in JS that's always running the code:

```
var d = document.getElementById("notify-wrapper");
d.value = null;
```

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is for you.

Comment: Web workers can't directly update the DOM. Why do you want to use a web worker for this, rather than setInterval() or setTimeout()? Also, it doesn't make sense to set an element value to null - perhaps you meant to set it to an empty string?